# Why aren't my songs showing up on my Creative Zen when I put an mp3 file on it using Ubuntu?

Tags: mp3, creative-zen

I transfered some mp3 songs onto my 8gb Creative Zen from Ubuntu and when I opened the music folder using the Creative Zen, it played the songs fine, but when I stopped the playback and asked my Zen itself to search for the songs, these files didn't even show up. Is there any specific reason it can be like that? Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: likely to be due to the ID tag - see this question and answer (http://askubuntu.com/questions/57082/is-there-a-cd-ripper-compatible-with-creative-zen-mx/57084#57084)  please add into your question what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

> "I have a 16 GB Creative Zen and it works great with Rhythmbox.
>   Open Rhythmbox, plug in your Zen. You'll see it open on the left hand side of the Rhythmbox window. Then you just drag & drop the albums/songs you want from the playlist and onto the Zen icon. Done."

source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1647971#post10252697